# Given any $\sin$ or $\cos$ involved parametric equation, how do I find its period?

Tags: calculus

Functions or parametric equation involves $\sin$ or $\cos$ have repeated pattern. How do I find the interval that contains exact one period?

Eg:

$F(\theta) = (\cos(\theta), \cos(3\theta))$. For what interval of $\theta$ that the whole curve is traced out ?

Comment: Here is a completely discrete version of the problem. With my left hand, a beat: Tap, Pause, Pause, Tap, Tap, Pause (TPPTTP). With the right, another: TTPP. What is the period of my two-handed rhythm? Generalize for simultaneous beats of generic length -- it's good fun!

Comment: PS. type `\sin` instead of `sin` to be typeset as a function.

Answer (score 1):

See period of $cos(x)=2\pi$ and that of $\cos(3x)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ as we divide the period of $\cos(x)$ with $n$ where $n\in R$ to get the period of $\cos(nx)$ now we take the lcm of the two periods which is $2\pi$ so period is $2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Take the period of the *x*-axis and the period of the *y*-axis and find the smallest number is a multiple of both periods.

For example if the periods are $\Phi_x$ and $\Phi_y$ then the shape period must be $$\Phi = n \Phi_x = m \Phi _y$$ where $n$ and $m$ are integers.